# Как правильно распарсить json

Tags: python, json

Не могу разобраться как этот json распарсить в массив..

```
response = requests.get(config.PRIVAT_ECHANGE).text
data = json.loads(response)


[
    {
        "ccy":"RUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"0.28000",
        "sale":"0.32000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"EUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"19.20000",
        "sale":"20.00000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"USD",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"15.50000",
        "sale":"15.85000"
    }
]
```

пытаюсь записать его в массив

```
exchanges = []

for item in data:
    exchanges += item
```

но получаеться

```
['ccy', 'base_ccy', 'buy', 'sale', 'ccy', 'base_ccy', 'buy', 'sale', 'ccy', 'base_ccy', 'buy', 'sale']
```

а я хочу чтобы в идеале при вызове было так

```
exchanges[0][ccy] + " " + 
exchanges[0][base_ccy] + " " + 
exchanges[0][buy] + " " + 
exchanges[0][sale]
```

Это будет код за один курс валют..

Comment: data = response.json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем решении ошибка. Во-первых, при попытке итерировать в цикле dict, то итерируются ключи, а не значения.
Во-вторых, Вам следовало этот кусочек с конкатенацией вставить как раз в цикле, итерируете список.
Приведу более изящное решение с генератором списков.

```
d = [
    {
        "ccy":"RUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"0.28000",
        "sale":"0.32000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"EUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"19.20000",
        "sale":"20.00000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"USD",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"15.50000",
        "sale":"15.85000"
    }
]

# с помощью генератора списков формируем список со строками
# с использование f-строк
o = [f'{r["ccy"]} {r["base_ccy"]} {r["buy"]} {r["sale"]}' for r in d]
```

Вывод:
`['RUR UAH 0.28000 0.32000', 'EUR UAH 19.20000 20.00000', 'USD UAH 15.50000 15.85000']`

Если нужно, чтобы каждая строка была разделена в списке, то вот вариант:

```
o2 = [(r["ccy"], r["base_ccy"], r["buy"], r["sale"]) for r in d]
```

Вывод следующий:
`[('RUR', 'UAH', '0.28000', '0.32000'), ('EUR', 'UAH', '19.20000', '20.00000'), ('USD', 'UAH', '15.50000', '15.85000')]`

Теперь список содержит кортежи (массивы), где лежат по отдельности значения на каждую строку

Comment: Ваш вариант по лучше.. Жаль что я еще только учу python. Оно выводит ['USD UAH 34.75000 35.55000', 'EUR UAH 36.70000 37.70000', 'BTC USD 25988.9024 28724.5764']. А тепер как мне отдельно выводит из первого элемента? Это нужно этот масив разделить на еще масивы?.

Comment: Чтобы получилось  o[0][ccy]

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите конкретно какой вывод Вы хотите получить

Comment: Есть https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5. Вот с него я хочу в телеграм вывести сообщение в котором будет USD to UAH : BUY/SALE /n RUR/UAH: BUY/SALE /n при этом почему я говорю чтобы я мог каждый элемент отдельно выводить, чтобы я придумла шаблон, может смайлы добавлю еще возле названия валют и т.д.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, где каждая строка делится на массивы, в каждом массивые каждое значение по отдельности, вероятно Вы так хотели получить вывод?

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за мой тупизм. не могли бы вы написать цыкл который выводит все значение в ряд одно валюты, потом второй валюты на новый ряд.. Я сегодня что то вообще в ауте не пойму  ничего.

Comment: @MSerega, если одной строкой: `for r in d: print(f'{r["ccy"]} {r["base_ccy"]} {r["buy"]} {r["sale"]}')`
Если кортежем (массивом): `for r in d: print((r["ccy"], r["base_ccy"], r["buy"], r["sale"]))`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное... с горем пополам сделал

Answer (score 1):

Ну начнем с того, что это не json, это список словарей. Если вы хотите получить таблицу, то лучше использовать Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd


data = [
    {
        "ccy":"RUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"0.28000",
        "sale":"0.32000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"EUR",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"19.20000",
        "sale":"20.00000"
    },
    {
        "ccy":"USD",
        "base_ccy":"UAH",
        "buy":"15.50000",
        "sale":"15.85000"
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
   ccy base_ccy       buy      sale
0  RUR      UAH   0.28000   0.32000
1  EUR      UAH  19.20000  20.00000
2  USD      UAH  15.50000  15.85000
```

Элементы извлекаются просто:

```
print(df['sale'])
print(df['buy'][1])
```

```
0     0.32000
1    20.00000
2    15.85000
Name: sale, dtype: object
19.20000
```

Comment: Там есть json, но с его парсингом проблем нет, просто человек неточно сформулировал проблему

Comment: @Sergey K Не одной форме JSON этот объект не соответствует. <https://www.json.org/json-ru.html>

Comment: `response = requests.get(config.PRIVAT_ECHANGE).text`
`data = json.loads(response)` Первые две строчки в вопросе прочитите. Там благополучно парсится json, а то, что вы имеете в виду - это уже распарсенный результат.